# How to request permissions in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app that needs to request permissions at run time.
I searched and couldn't find a solution on how to do it in Jetpack Compose.

How can I request/check permissions at runtime from a `@Composable` function? (my functions are nested deep so I have no access to the activity instance)

I would like to have something like:

```
@Composable()
fun test() {
  val hasPermission = checkPermission("READ_CONTACTS")
  if (hasPermission)
    LoadData()
  else
    requestPermission("READ_CONTACTS")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with the [`1.3.0-alpha06`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity)  of `androidx.activity:activity-compose` you can use the **`rememberLauncherForActivityResult`** to register a request to `Activity#startActivityForResult`.

Something like:

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission Accepted 
        } else {
            // Permission Denied 
        }
    }
```

Then just use it:

```
val context = LocalContext.current

Button(
    onClick = {
        
        when {
            //Check permission
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                // You can use the API that requires the permission.

            } else -> {
                 // Asking for permission
                 launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Button")
}
```

Comment: How do you request for multiple permissions at a go?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how to request rational message on that bases..?

Comment: @JeffreyNyauke, we have another RequestMultiplePermissions variant for that case.