# Can't list the files in the folder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My code:

```
suspend fun loadLocalSongs(context: Context) {
        var path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).absolutePath
        path = path + File.separator + "SongsManager/"
        val baseFile = File(path)
        val test = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        
        Log.i("========exists", baseFile.exists().toString())
        Log.i("========canread", baseFile.canRead().toString())

        if (baseFile.isDirectory) {
            var files = baseFile.list()

            Log.i("=========", "yes")
            for (file in baseFile.listFiles()!!) {
                Log.i("fileName:", file.name)
            }
        }
    }
```

My folder structure:
[image]

the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

build.gradle:

```
namespace 'com.example.bellavoice'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bellavoice"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
```

Please Help, thanks a lot.

when I didn't add "SongsManager/", the code work well and lists the correct result: "QQMusic","ringtone","SongsManager" and so on.
However, whenn I add  "SongsManager/" to the path, the code didn't work. baseFile exists, can read and is a directory. But baseFile.listFiles() is empty.

Comment: What is wrong with string "SongsManger" (without slash)?

Comment: @Reporter same. I found that baseFile.listFiles() can list folders but cannot list files. For example, I create a new folder in SongsManager called testFolder, it can be listed. However, common files can't.

Comment: What is the value of `File.separator`? What is the output of `path = path + File.separator + "SongsManager/"`? May be you should add some output for better debugging.

Comment: You can read files you have created by this function in scoped storage.

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue on myself:

```
val refreshLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGrant ->
        if (isGrant) {
            coroutineScope.launch { songVM.loadLocalSongs() }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "please grant permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    }
```

Need to check self permission and ask for permission if its not granted:

```
onClick = {
    when {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
            coroutineScope.launch { songVM.loadLocalSongs() }
        }
        else -> {
            refreshLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [How to request permissions in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636796/how-to-request-permissions-in-jetpack-compose)